# Laravel Eloquent - Define relationship to one of three possible tables based on value of column in parent table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Let's say I have a blog post with a comment section. Using Laravel Eloquent I get data from the 'comments' table and the relational 'users' table. Something like this:

```
Comment::where('post_id', $post_id)
       ->with('user')
       ->get();
```

The 'users' table has a column called 'user_type' with the value 'user' or 'admin'.

If the `user_type` in the `users` table is `user` I want to get relational data from the `regular_users` table like this: `->with(user.regular_user)`.

If the `user_type` in the `users` table is `admin` I want to get relational data from the `admins` table like this: `->with('user.admin')`

(All the relationships are defined properly in the models.)

How do I do this?

Comment: you can create a view in mysql

Comment: Why not just eager load both, regardless of type? `with('user', 'user.regular_user', 'user.admin')`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of with, try the following with `whereHas`:

i.e.:

```
$regular_users = Comment::where('post_id', $post_id)
   ->whereHas('user',function ($user) {
       $user->where('user_type', 'user')->with('regular_user');
   })       
->get();
```

Comment: N+1 problem ! It's a performance killer problem ;) I heavily recommend to remove the answer !

Comment: Yeah, you're def right. Not the best to make query calls like this. Eloquent `whereHad` function might make more sense here.